# Why is my java docker image created successfully on laptop but when uploading to google cloud run it fails?

Tags: java, docker, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

dockerfile:

```
FROM maven as builder
# Set the working directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/mymaven
COPY ./ /usr/src/mymaven
CMD [ "maven:3.3-jdk-8" , "mvn" , "clean" , "install" ]

FROM openjdk:8
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/mymaven/target /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
CMD ["java", "-jar" , "Build-Backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

In local build is successful using the command:

```
docker build -t javaservice .
```

But when trying to upload image to google cloud run using command:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/$(gcloud config get-value project)/javaservice
```

It gives error:

```
Step 6/8 : COPY --from=builder /usr/src/mymaven/target /usr/src/myapp
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/201005fffe25fce26b6ef6067586ae02dd20a0ad7d63b846d5ee6260d833d52d/merged/usr/src/mymaven/target: no such file or directory
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

What might be wrong here?

Comment: Does the target directory exist before the first step? Can you check by adding a first step 'debian ls'? If your local machine OS is different from the worker, it may be an issue.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't exist :(

Comment: You can try by adding a `/` at the end of `COPY ./ /usr/src/mymaven`. Sometimes clouds have a tough time without `/`.

Comment: Didn't work. The solution I posted below worked flawlessly though

Comment: The issue is the _COPY_ instruction, which copies the files in _src_ to _dest_ folder. When building from Cloud Build, it looks like you're missing one of the files or most likely copying it from the wrong directory. Check your path directory and see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find an answer so posting the solution that I found on my own.
If you can build docker images on local machine but google cloud run is failing for whatever reason, you can push the locally made image directly to google container registry.

```
gcloud auth configure-docker #integrate gcloud to docker
docker build . --tag gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGENAME]
docker push gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGENAME]
```

Source: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/building/containers

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `target` directory in your local directory is being ignored, either by `.gitignore` or `.gcloudignore`, and thus isn't being sent to Cloud Build.